# Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['moneybooks/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$

Tags: python, django

I made a update function, but error occur like below:

> NoReverseMatch at /moneybooks/1/
>   Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['moneybooks/update/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

i try many things... but don't know what's problem.

## datail.html

```
  <a href="{% url "moneybooks:update" moneybooks.pk %}">Update Moneybook</a></br>
```

## views.py

```
class moneybook_update(UpdateView):
    form_class = forms.UpdateMoneybookForm
    template_name = "moneybooks/update.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneybook = form.save()
        moneybook.owner = self.request.user
        moneybook.save()
        return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
```

## url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "moneybooks"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.moneybook_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
]
```

## form.py

```
class UpdateMoneybookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Moneybook
        fields = (
            "name",
            "companion",
            "country",
            "location",
            "start_date",
            "end_date",
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        moneybook = super().save(commit=False)
        return moneybook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using double quotes outside then use single quotes inside or vice versa, also don't write `moneybooks.pk` directly but `pk=moneybooks.pk` -

```
<a href="{% url 'moneybooks:update' pk=moneybooks.pk %}">Update Moneybook</a></br>
```

Comment: i try it but 
>Reverse for 'update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['moneybooks/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

and i think double quotes is not a problem i guess.

Comment: i think `moneybooks.pk` is not valid, try to display `{{moneybooks.pk}}` is getting any value?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{% url 'moneybooks:update' pk=object.pk %}">Update Moneybook</a></br>
```

In detail view you will get your object as object, so object.pk should work

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue and it turns out I put the URL outside the for loop that was looping through the objects which then resulted in the error.

So, in your `detail.html`, you will need to set a `for` loop that loops all the object in the `moneybooks` class, and then put

```
<a href="{% url 'moneybooks:update' moneybooks.pk %}">Update Moneybook</a></br>
```

inside the loop. I hope it makes sense.